# Easiest way to post to a server on iPhone? I don't care about the response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, post, asynchronous

I've looked at some of the apple core API stuff, as well as ASIHTTPRequest. It's made me curious - is there a simple way to just send a nonblocking request to a URL? I could do it what seems to be the standard way - make the request object, make a useless delegate object that just ignores the response, and that's how I've been doing it. I'm still pretty new to ObjC in general, so I was wondering if I missed out on something that could save me from writing all this boilerplate code.

If only I could run curl.

Comment: You could skip the "useless delegate" if you want. Just pass in a `nil` as the delegate parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for all connections.  It is a CFNetwork wrapper that is much better than the default Apple NSUrlRequest

Comment: Definitely a good way to go. OP: you say you don't care about the response, but applications often grow in complexity quickly, and NSURLRequest doesn't handle concurrent calls well.